# Populate a WTForms form object with a datetime.date

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I'm cooking up a crud interface for an object representing a bill, as in the water bill, the electric bill, etc.

I'm using sqlalchemy to handle the data, wtforms to handle the forms, and flask to serve it.

Here's what my route looks like that serves the form for editing an existing bill:

```
@app.route('/edit_bill/<int:bill_id>', methods = ['GET'])
def edit_bill(bill_id):
    s = Session()
    bill = s.query(Bill).filter_by(id=bill_id).first()
    form = BillForm(obj=Bill)
    return render_template('edit_bill.html', form = form)
```

Using wtforms, I pass the bill object to the BillForm constructor, ensuring that the data representing the bill to be edited it populated to the form.

This is where it chokes.  Here's the exception:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Bill.date_due has an attribute 'strftime'
```

Now, I've dipped into the python shell and queried up a bill to make sure that date_due has a `datetime.date` object on it, which is does.  I use Jinja to build my front end, so I've looked into creating a template filter, but I don't know how that would work with wtforms, and it looks like sqlalchemy is the one choking anyway.

So what it do?  I'm pretty confident I just need to figure out how to turn that `datetime.date` object into a string, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Halp. Thanks!

**Edit:  Here's the BillForm class:**

```
class BillForm(Form):
    id                  = HiddenField()
    name                = TextField(u'Name:', [validators.required()])
    pay_to              = TextField(u'Pay To:',[validators.required()])
    date_due            = DateField(u'Date Due:',[validators.required()])
    amount_due          = IntegerField(u'Amount Due:', [validators.required()])
    date_late           = DateField(u'Late After:',[validators.required()])
    amount_late         = IntegerField(u'Late Amount:', [validators.required()])
    date_termination    = DateField(u'Termination Date:',[validators.required()])
```

**And mapping class, too:**

```
class Bill(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bills'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    pay_to = Column(String)
    amount_due = Column(Integer)
    date_due = Column(Date)
    amount_late = Column(Integer)
    date_late = Column(Date)
    date_termination = Column(Date)

    def __init__(self, name, pay_to, amount_due, date_due, amount_late, date_late, date_termination):
        self.name               = name
        self.pay_to             = pay_to
        self.amount_due         = amount_due
        self.date_due           = date_due
        self.amount_late        = amount_late
        self.date_late          = date_late
        self.date_termination   = date_termination

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Bill ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')>" % (self.name, self.pay_to, self.amount_due, self.date_due)
```

Comment: May we see the form code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah it took me some time to figure out where you went wrong, but think I found it out. Here's your code:

```
@app.route('/edit_bill/<int:bill_id>', methods = ['GET'])
def edit_bill(bill_id):
    s = Session()
    bill = s.query(Bill).filter_by(id=bill_id).first()
    form = BillForm(obj=Bill)
    return render_template('edit_bill.html', form = form)
```

Now, if pass a class as the `obj` kwarg in BillForm, the form gets populated with all kinds of strange objects. For example, if I replicate what you did and inspect `form.date_due.data`, it says it is an `<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute at 0x277b2d0>` object. Like what is stated in the error message, this object does not have a `strftime` attribute.

So, your error is in line 5 of the code you presented. If you want to populate the form with the details of the bill object you retrieved in line 4, replace line 5 with `form = BillForm(obj=bill)`. As you can see, the 'subtle' difference is the lowercase b in bill. I replicated your code and am convinced should fix the problem.

If you're interested, this is how I normally make edit views.

```
@app.route('/edit_bill/<int:bill_id>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_bill(bill_id):
    s = Session()
    bill = s.query(Bill).filter_by(id=bill_id).first()
    form = BillForm(request.form, obj=bill)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        form.populate_obj(bill)
        s.add(bill)
        s.commit()
        # Do some other stuff, for example set a flash()
    return render_template('edit_bill.html', form = form)
```

I haven't used SQLAlchemy for a while so I might have made a couple of mistakes there. Hope this helps! If this answers your question 'accept' the answer.

Comment: oh my god, i am screaming in my head right now. duh you have to pass the instance, not the class!  oi vey.  i like your edit route better.  i've seen that pattern in rails (if GET serve form with data, if POST persist data from form) and i'm totally going to use it.  

thanks!